# Cannot install GTK+3.6.4

Tags: installation, gtk, dependencies, glib, pango

When trying to run the **./configure** for gtk+-3.6.4 I get the following:

> Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.35.3' but version of GLib is 2.34.0
>
> Requested 'atk >= 2.7.5' but version of Atk is 2.4.0
>
> Requested 'pango >= 1.32.4' but version of Pango is 1.30.0
>
> Requested 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.27.1' but version of GdkPixbuf is 2.26.1

I downloaded the latest tars and installed them all with **./configure && make** then as *root* **make install** without an issue, but the problem persists.

I'm running a fresh installation of 12.0.4.2 64bit with all other updates performed before I even started trying to install GTK3.6.4.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need 3.8.1?

Comment: Got mixed up and meant to say 3.6.4 (both times), sorry. Was reading about it and happened to type what else was on my mind.

Comment: Which os you are using

Comment: Ubuntu 12.0.4.2 64bit.
@thefourtheye Need GTK+3.6.4 for DeSmuME 0.9.9.

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.04 GTK 3.6.4-0ubuntu8 is already installed

Comment: dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0

Comment: @Qasim I'm just going to update to 13.04 then. This was a fresh install anyways so nothing lost.

Answer (score 0):

In your Ubuntu 12.04 installation, add a software repository from (12.10 or 13.04) that contains already the debian package for gtk 3.6.4

Then force that highest version for your gtk-package. And lock it, so it will not be updated.